# Is it possible to dynamic_cast between two unrelated types, if they share a common (possibly unknown) child class?

Tags: c++, templates, polymorphism, dynamic-cast, static-cast

Sorry if the question title makes no sense, but I'm not sure how to succinctly describe the problem I'm trying to solve. Here's the issue:

1. I'm working with a C++ library that makes heavy use of a class which we'll call `Base`
2. This library has several different child classes that inherit from `Base`. We'll call these classes `Child1`, `Child2`, .. etc.
3. This library allows the user create their own child classes of `Base` and have the library use instances of those classes. I currently have something like this:

```
class Custom : public Child1 // inherit from Child1, which inherits from Base
{
public:
  // override virtual functions here
  // ...
  void doSomething(); // Utility function I created
}
```

and then the library I'm using will have some function like this:

```
void foo(Base* base);
```

I can pass in a pointer to my `Custom` class no problem, everything's fine. There are also times where I might need to receive a pointer to a `Base` object from the library and do stuff with it. That looks something like this:

```
// code...
Base *base = getSomeBase(); // getSomeBase() is a function from the library that returns a Base*
Custom* myCustom = static_cast<Custom*>(base); // I always make the library use my `Custom` class, so this is safe.
myCustom->doSomething();
```

This also works without issue. I'm able to invoke my custom `doSomething()` method by performing a `static_cast`. However...I now have the need to have more than one possible `Custom` class. Specifically, I need make the appropriate "child" class to inherit from a template parameter in my `Custom` class. My code now looks like this:

```
template <class Child_t>
class Custom : public Child_t // inherit from Child_t, which inherits from Base
{
public:
  // override virtual functions here
  // ...
  void doSomething(); // Utility function I created
}
```

There is no issue in making the library use my new templated `Custom<>` class because as long as the template parameter `Child_t` is in fact one of the library's child classes that inherit from `Base`, my `Custom<>` class can simply be cast to a `Base*`. The issue arises when trying to go in the other direction:

```
Base *base = getSomeBase();
/* ?????
  Would like to call base->doSomething();
  But I have no idea which Custom class I have received here. "base" could be
  a Child1*, Child2*, etc. There's no way for me to perform a cast.
*/
```

I am stuck. Note that my function `doSomething()` will have identical behavior regardless of which `Custom<>` class I have received from the library. My initial thought was to move my `doSomething()` function to an interface class.

```
class Interface
{
public:
  virtual void doSomething() = 0;
}
```

And then have each `Custom<>` class implement the interface like so:

```
template <class Child_t>
class Custom : public Child_t, public Interface
{

  void doSomething() override;
}
```

This ends up being unhelpful, as the compiler will not allow me to do the following:

```
Base *base = getSomeBase();
Interface* interface = static_cast<Interface*>(base); // Error: can't static_cast between unrelated types.
interface->doSomething();
```

The compiler says that `Interface` and `Base` are unrelated types. I know for a fact that any `Base*` I receive is actually an `Interface*`, but the compiler can't know that and, I'm guessing, cannot perform the correct pointer adjustment to convert the `Base*` to an `Interface*`. At this point I'm stuck and am not sure what to do. I need to call my `doSomething()` function on whatever `Base*` I get from the library, but I have no idea which custom child class I'm actually getting. The only solution I currently see is to exhaustively `dynamic_cast` to every possible child class.

```
Base *base = getSomeBase(); // getSomeBase()
if (auto* c1 = dynamic_cast<Custom<Child1>*>(base))
{
  c1->doSomething();
}
else if (auto* c2 = dynamic_cast<Custom<Child2>*>(base))
{
  c2->doSomething();
}
```

This is an ugly solution. It also places extra cognitive load on the developer because if at any point they decide they need to use a `Custom<Child3>`, `Custom<Child4>`, `Custom<Child5>`, etc. class, they must remember to go back and update the if-else chain to exhaustively check for each possible case. So my question is:

1. Is it possible to somehow invoke my `doSomething()` function on the `Base*` object without actually knowing which `Custom<>` class I have at compile time, and without simply trying every possible `dynamic_cast`? Hence the title of my question: can I somehow cast a `Base*` to an `Interface*`, given that I know for a fact that they share a common child class (I just don't know *which* child class).
2. Am I going about this in the completely wrong way?

Comment: `dynamic_cast<Interface*>(base)`?

Comment: ...Or if there is just one possible `Interface`, I'd consider the opportunity to put the various `virtual void doSomething() = 0;` directly in `Base`, avoiding multiple inheritance and dynamic casts. The initial approach downcasting `Base` to `Custom` to call a specialized method sounds suspect and I would review the design decision that lead to that

Comment: @MatG Yes, ideally the interface would be on `Base`. But `Base` is a class that comes from a library I am linking against which I do not have the full source code for (only .h files files and a .lib file). So I cannot modify `Base` to contain the `doSomething()` function.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you should use `dynamic_cast<Interface*>(base)`

---

```cpp
struct B{virtual ~B(){}};
struct I{virtual int foo()=0;};

struct X:B{};
struct Y:I,X{virtual int foo(){return 10;}};
struct Z:I,X{virtual int foo(){return 20;}};

int main(){
    B* x = new Z;
    I* i = dynamic_cast<I*>(x);
    return i->foo();
}
```

http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/f7a5787cb9fe80be

Comment: Thank you so much! For some reason I just assumed that dynamic_cast wouldn't be able to perform this type of cast. I guess I was under the impression that dynamic_cast and static_cast had the exact same limitations on what types you can cast between. Now I know better! I should have just tried dynamic_cast from the start.

Comment: @ChristianDaley No problem :)  you do provide good question with details too :)